# MYSQL select from two tabels

Tags: php, mysql

I Have to tabels
TABLE A

```
id | title | content
```

TABLE B

```
id | id_from_table_a | user_id | already_seen
```

I cant find good query to mysql which will by show something like this:

```
show all from table A  whitout  where user_id='user_logged_id' and  already_seen='yes'
```

<sup>*Pseudo code above*</sup>

it is big database so join's will by probably be a better solution.

Comment: I would use `table B` only to track which items have been seen. That means you do not need the last column, the mere fact that the combination `id_from_table_a` and `user_id` exists means that the user has seen that item.

Comment: If what you mean by "whitout" is that you want to returns rows from table A where there is no "matching" row found in table B, an **anti-join pattern** is usually the most efficient pattern. That's an outer join that returns all rows from A along with matching rows from B, with a predicate that excludes all rows that had a match, leaving those that didn't have a match. (I'll give an example in an answer.)

Answer (score 2):

This is done without join :

```
select * from tableA where id not in 
(select id_from_table_a from tableB where user_id='user_logged_id' and  already_seen='yes')
```

or with join :

```
select a.id, a.tittle, a.content from tableA a left join tableB b
on a.id = b.id_from_table_a 
where b.user_id <> 'user_logged_id' and  b.already_seen <> 'yes'
group by a.id, a.tittle, a.content
```

Comment: hym... this without join works but join method doesnt'`

Comment: @PawełMiłosz : Try again.

Comment: @PawełMiłosz : take a look on Spencer answer if your condition meet his criteria. That is good way for your problem.

Comment: For the query with the `NOT IN (subquery)` we need to *guarantee* that the subquery does *not* return a NULL value, because if it does return a `NULL`, then the outer query won't return any rows. If the `id_from_table_a` column in table B is defined as `NOT NULL`, then we have that guarantee, and everything is good. But if not (and we don't have enough information to know whether it is or not), we can give a guarantee by including another predicate in the subquery... **`AND id_from_table_a IS NOT NULL`**. Then the query itself guarantees that it won't return a NULL.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what you meant by `whitout` but you can change the query accordingly to the typo.  I believe something like this is what you're looking for?

```
SELECT * FROM TableA as a 
    JOIN TableB as b ON a.id = b.id_from_table_a
WHERE 
    b.user_id = 'user_logged_in' AND b.already_seen = 'yes';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM tableA 
JOIN TableB 
ON tableA.id = TableB.tableA-id 
WHERE already-seen = "yes" AND user-id != :user-logged-id
```

Comment: what mean of `:user-logged-in`?

Comment: @ColourDalnet It's a [parametrized query](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.bindparam.php).

Comment: Changed "n" to "d". and yes, it's a variable

Comment: yes, but this is not complete code without binding the parameter.

Answer (score 0):

That's how i join 2 tables

```
 SELECT * FROM TableA
    INNER JOIN TableB on TableA.id=TableB.id_from_table_a 
                      and TableB.user_id='user_logged_id' 
                      and TableB.already_seen='yes'
```

Answer (score 0):

An example of a query using an **anti-join** pattern to return the specified result:

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.title
     , a.content
  FROM table_a a
  LEFT
  JOIN table_b b
    ON b.id_from_table_a = a.id
   AND b.already_seen    = 'yes'
   AND b.user_id         = 'user_logged_in'
 WHERE b.already_seen IS NULL
```

Let's unwrap that a bit.

We're returning ALL rows from table_a, along with "matching" rows from table_b. To be considered a "match", the row has to satisfy the predicates in the ON clause (the `id_from_table_a` column has to match, and the `already_seen` and `user_id` columns have to satisfy the conditions.

The `LEFT JOIN` is an **outer join**. It returns all rows from the table on the left side (that satisfy the predicates in the WHERE clause), and returns matching rows from the table on the right side. (In a normal **inner join**, rows from table_a that don't have a matching row from table_b are excluded. With the **outer join**, the rows without a match *will* be returned.)

The "trick" is to exclude rows that had a match. And we do that here with a predicate (condition) in the `WHERE` clause. We are testing a column which we know will be non-NULL on a matching row. (Any matching row from table_b will have a non-NULL value for the `already_seen` column, we are guaranteed that by the condition in the `ON` clause... matching rows will all have a value of `'yes'` for the already_seen column. (We could reference any column from table_b that is guaranteed to be non-null... if the `id` column in table_b is defined as NOT NULL or is the PRIMARY KEY, we could use that.)

For rows in `table_a` that didn't have a matching row, we know that `already_seen` column will be `NULL`. So we exclude all matching rows, leaving only rows from table_a that didn't have a match.

---

**FOLLOWUP**

**Q:** Is this anti-join will give faster result than normal where b.user_id <> 'user_logged_id' and b.already_seen <> 'yes' ? –  Colour Dalnet 5 mins ago

**A:** The anti-join will give a *different* result than a query that checks for not equals conditions on the columns in table_b. Those tests would negate the "outerness" of a `LEFT JOIN`, rendering it equivalent to an `INNER JOIN`. The anti-join pattern will return the specified result, rows from table_a that don't have a "matching" row in table_b.

As far as performance, the anti-join is usually the most efficient, though other query patterns can be just as fast. (For some other query patterns that return the same result, the execution plan is identical. Other statements can have different execution plans, and those are usually slower, but there are some cases they are actually faster.)

As examples of two other patterns, a `NOT IN` predicate... (note that we need to guarantee that a `NULL` value is *not* included in the set returned by the subquery.)

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.title
     , a.content
  FROM table_a a
 WHERE a.id NOT IN 
       ( SELECT b.id_from_table_a
           FROM table_b b
          WHERE b.already_seen = 'yes'
            AND b.user_id      = 'user_logged_in'
            AND b.id_from_table_a IS NOT NULL
       )
```

And for completeness, an example of a `NOT EXISTS` correlated subquery pattern that returns an equivalent result:

```
SELECT a.id
     , a.title
     , a.content
  FROM table_a a
 WHERE NOT EXISTS 
       ( SELECT 1 
           FROM table_b b
          WHERE b.already_seen    = 'yes'
            AND b.user_id         = 'user_logged_in'
            AND b.id_from_table_a = a.id
       )
```

You can check the output from `EXPLAIN SELECT ...` to see the actual execution plans for each statement. Depending on the version of MySQL, the execution plans may be identical or may be different. The "optimizer" (the section of MySQL code responsible for transforming SQL text into an execution plan) has had some significant changes in some of the major releases.)

Comment: Is this **anti-join** will give faster result than normal `where b.user_id <> 'user_logged_id' and  b.already_seen <> 'yes'` ?

Comment: @ColourDalnet: The anti-join will give a *different* result than testing not equals conditions, which would negate the "outerness" of a LEFT JOIN, rendering it equivalent to an INNER JOIN. The anti-join pattern will return the specified result. As far as performance, the anti-join is usually the most efficient, though other query patterns can be just as fast. (For some queries, the execution plan is identical.) For statements with different execution plans are usually slower, but there are cases they are faster.

Comment: Owh, I'm sorry. I didn't read your edited explanation. This is my first time seeing this.

Comment: @ColourDalnet: The **anti-join** pattern is a bit much to get your head wrapped around. But once you understand how it works, it's a very useful tool to keep in the toolbelt. I've added FOLLOWUP to my answer. including two additional query patterns (a `NOT IN` and and `NOT EXISTS`) that will return an equivalent result. Use `EXPLAIN` to compare the query execution plans. (Queries with identical query plans should give the same performance.)

Comment: Yes, I understand it now. Thank you very much. @PawelMilosz : Try this answer.

Comment: I do some quick test with this **anti-join** between 2319 `tableA` and 7420 `tableB`. It's need 42 seconds with `NOT IN` and 35 seconds with `anti-join`. But make sure `already_seen` never contains `NULL` value or it will give wrong result. Time will be different with complexity and PC Performance, but yes **anti-join** is faster than `NOT IN` in this case.